# Entity Framework Core 2.0 execute stored procedure that doesn't return a PK

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, primary-key, .net-core-2.0

EF Core 2.0 seems to require that the results of executing a stored procedure have a primary key. Is there a way around this? Not all stored procedures return uniquely identifiable rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not currently possible with EF Core, but it is on the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/roadmap) for a future version, though perhaps not for v2.1. See these issues on GitHub:

- [#1862 Raw store access APIs: Support for ad hoc mapping of arbitrary types](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862)
- [#9290 Query Types: Model types that do not require identity](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9290)
- [#10753 Model: Dynamic introduction of types.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10753)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a slightly glaring omission. Hopefully in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as well when I was doing development.  You can always dummy a self incrementing key return in SQL Server directly with something as simple as Row_Number() Over() as [ObjectName]Id.  This is a cheap hack but it was satisfy the need as you can then set your POCO with adornment of [Key] over this field that gets return and it will be distinct in an otherwise non distinct return.

```
declare @Temp table ( val char);

insert into @Temp values ('a'),('b'),('c');

select 
  --this column is arbitrarily made and only exists to satisfy uniqueness.
  --it provides NO functionality to the underlying code being returned.
  ROW_NUMBER() Over(order by val) as TempId
, val 
from @Temp
```

And the model for the return:

```
public sealed class pTempResult
{
    [Key]
    public int TempId{ get; set; }
    public int Val { get; set; }
}
```

For what I did I also enabled a DbSet object in my context I created too:

```
public virtual DbSet<pTempResult> { get; set; }
```

Then in my controller I would call it with something like this:

```
await _context.pTempResult.FromSql("pMyProc @p0, @p1, @p2", parameters: new[] { 1, "string" }).ToListAsync();
```

This way I am getting a well formed object but at the same time calling the procedure directly that I need to get this well formed object.  Keep in mind in Entity Framework Core AFAIK you have to add a migration to create the proc if it does not already exist.  EG: If I want to populate the procedures in the database from the code I need to write the SQL manually in the 'up' section of a migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
   migrationBuilder.Sql(
   "create proc pGetTemp" +
   "( @Id int,  @Text varchar(16) as " +
   "BEGIN " +
   "Select * from Temp " +
   "Where Id = @Id and text = @Text " +
   "END "
   ); 
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
   migrationBuilder.Sql("drop proc pGetTemp");
}
```

Again this is not pretty and not optimal but if you want to use Procedures with Entity Framework Core I can verify this will work.

Comment: Thanks! I'd considered something similar, but with hundreds of stored procedures already in place, it's not practical, and also doesn't seem right to have to tinker with the SQL to accommodate the thing that's consuming it. Hopefully EF Core will mature into something as useful as its previously (EF6) incarnation.

Comment: Keep in mind even with a complex database you can get most of these scripts for views and procedures(potentially more functions and triggers too) with 'select object_name(object_id), definition from sys.sql_modules' from SQL Server's 'sys' catalog directly.  I have done this before when I needed to examine a bunch of scripts for pseudo reflection work.  As well as tools like Redgate that have meta information you can get as well.  Plus you don't HAVE TO do this.  It is merely there if you need to redeploy to another environment to have in a migration.